# Combining two different iterable types in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, generator, iterable

lets assume I have two types of iterables, one of them being a list and the other a generator object (or if it is easier view both as lists)

the list has the following elements: `list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` on the other hand the generator yields a list of tuples in each iteration, the yielded list looks like this: `ylist = [(3,"three"),(4,"four"),(5,"five")]`.

I want to be able to get a list which will look like this: `finallist = [1,2,(3,"three"),(4,"four"),(5,"five"),6,7,8,9]`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What happens if the list of tuples has elements which aren't present in the other list?  E.g., how do you combine `[1, 2, 3]` with `[(5, "five")]`?

Comment: You're not concatenating the iterables. Concatenating would be sticking the items of one onto the end of the other.

Comment: I think you want to include your actual code, and explain why you are trying to do this. What is the final object meant to represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the return items from that generator to a dict and then use a list comprehension:

```
>>> lis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> ylist = [(3, "three"),(4, "four"),(5, "five")]
>>> dic = dict(ylist)
>>> [x if x not in dic else (x, dic[x])  for x in lis]
[1, 2, (3, 'three'), (4, 'four'), (5, 'five'), 6, 7, 8, 9]
```